# log4net IsDebugEnabled not true using plugin dll

Tags: c#, log4net

i create plugin project for some third party, on that project i use log4net.dll.but  it is not working(IsDebugEnabled is false and log file not created.).

I am using log4net.dll in one sample application(not plugin project) in that application it is working perfectly.
that means IsDebugEnabled is true and the log file is created.

the below steps i have followed:
1.create app.config file and add below code.

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
```

2.Create another config file, name is log4net.config

```
<log4net>
<appender name="DEBUG_APPENDER" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${USERPROFILE}\Logs\Log.txt" />
  <additivity value="true" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="300KB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %method - %message %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="DEBUG_APPENDER"/>
</root>
```

OutputDirectory is CopyAlways.

3.Add this line to AssemblyInfo.cs file.

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

1. And finally use to classes.

   ```
       private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
       Log.Debug("DEBUG");
   ```

the above code i have used in my sample project and plugin code.
but it is working in sample project , not working in plugin project.

i don't know what mistakes i did. please give some solutions.

Comment: Try removing the line `<additivity value="true" />` as I don't think that is valid.

Comment: thanks for your response. i think [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)] does not read the config file. if i give the absolute path in ConfigFile proprty it is working.

Comment: i think in the library project [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)] it is not working. Watch property only finds the app.exe.config. so i use log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(log4netConfig)); it is working well.